# Is there any performance cost in breaking up a single Where() with && into 2 Where() calls (in EF)?

Tags: entity-framework

In Entity Framework, is there any performance cost of doing this...

`var businesses = dbContext.Businesses.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(name) && businessTypes.Contains(x.Type));`

... versus this?

`var businesses = dbContext.Businesses.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(name)).Where(x => businessTypes.Contains(x.Type));`

I prefer to do the latter since it's easier to read, but not if there's a serious performance hit on the generated SQL.

Comment: In debugging it, you can see the actual SQL generated.

Comment: Yeah, I know - I wanted to get the knowledge out there publicly, plus I figured someone knew the answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no performance cost - the EF Linq provider maps both to the same SQL query. I personally find the first version much more readable though.